# Ansible: How to hide password in 'shell'?

Tags: jenkins, ansible, ansible-facts

I am running a job in Jenkins which runs an Ansible playbook. The Ansible playbook fetches some credentials which I don't want it to be printed in the console log of Jenkins. The credentials are being used in the same playbook for a `curl` command.

Is there a way to obfuscate just the password part by ****? If not, can the `curl <...>` be hidden and just print its output in the log?

My code is something like this

```yaml
- name: curl
  shell: "curl -u '{{ user }}:{{ password }}'"
```

Comment: you should be able to set `no_log: true` to hide passwort output on console

Comment: From the doc: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#keep-secret-data "Note that the use of the no_log attribute does not prevent data from being shown when debugging Ansible itself through the ANSIBLE_DEBUG environment variable."

Answer (score -2):

The `no_log: true` option will not prevent output when running the playbook in [verbose (`-vvv`) mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-v).

I guess a better method is to store this command in a shell-script, let's say `do_curl.sh`, use the `template` or `copy` module to upload it to the Remote Machine and run it with `shell` or `command` module.

E.g.

```bash
#!/bin/env bash
curl -u '{{ user }}:{{ password }}' "$@"
```

So you can use this for multiple requests:

```yaml
shell: "do_curl.sh {{url}}"
```

If you don't want to leave the script (with the credentials) on the Target Machine you can use `file` with `state: absent` to remove the script immediately after running it. (Also limit it's file permissions in the copy/template task.)

If you don't want this script with the credentials on your Ansible Control Machine (and/or in the playbooks (`git`) repo), store it with the right permissions on the Target Machine. Or instantiate as a template with credentials from [Ansible vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/vault_guide/index.html).